# RabbitMQ LDAP Configuration

Tags: windows, authentication, ldap, rabbitmq

How can I configure RabbitMQ to support LDAP authentication on Windows?

I have tried to use the following in both rabbitmq.config and advanced.config (anonymized so I could post it here). I have tried using rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap and rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.

```
[
  {rabbit, [{auth_backends, [rabbit_auth_backend_ldap]}]},
  {rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap,        
    {servers, ["server1", "server2"]},
    {timeout, infinity},
    {log, true},
    {dn_lookup_attribute,   "sAMAccountName"},
    {dn_lookup_base,        "DC=a,DC=b"},
    {user_dn_pattern, "${username}@domain.com"},
    {vhost_access_query, {in_group, "ou=${vhost}-users,ou=vhosts,dc=example,dc=com"}}
    }
].
```

However in all cases, I get the following message in the logs.

> 2018-04-18 11:45:28.048 [warning] <0.452.0> LDAP plugin loaded, but rabbit_auth_backend_ldap is not in the list of auth_backends. LDAP auth will not work.~n

The log message reads rabbit_auth_backend_ldap regardless of whether I use  rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap or rabbit_auth_backend_ldap. The documentation mentions both [rabbit_auth_backend_ldap](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/bb36e18a0ab25117ca8ccf3aecd58bdd3985006b/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example#L111) and [rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/1b0096a925ba56af16d4776713a5c8e9593c587a/docs/advanced.config.example#L82) .

I have installed the plugin and see the following in the log.

```
2018-04-19 09:27:02.354 [info] <0.5.0> Server startup complete; 4 plugins started.
 * rabbitmq_management
 * rabbitmq_management_agent
 * rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap
 * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
```

Comment: Did you enable the plugin? https://www.rabbitmq.com/ldap.html#enabling-the-plugin

Comment: @LutzHorn yes I enabled the plugin.

Comment: Does it work with the correct name?

Comment: No, I just made the change and restarted the service. I still get the same error though.

Comment: [`rabbitmq-users` thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rabbitmq-users/9iBRc7x7XvY/discussion). I'm currently waiting for the output of `rabbitmqctl environment`, which should give us useful information as to what is going on. FWIW, I have supplied Ryan an `advanced.config` file that works in my Windows environment.